# Derivative of $f(x,y(x))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I tried to take the derivative of $f(x,y(x))$ with respect to $x$ but end up with $f_x+f_y*f_x$. But this is wrong. It should be $f_x+f_y*f$. What did I miss?

Comment: They are both wrong, it should be 
$ \frac{df}{dx} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confusion could be avoid if one is more careful with notations.

Write $F(x)=f(x,g(x))$ where $f$ is a map from ${\bf R}^2$ to ${\bf R}$:
$$
(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)
$$
and $g$ is a map from ${\bf R}$ to ${\bf R}$:
$$
x\mapsto g(x).
$$

Now we can apply the chain rule:
$$
F'(x)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,g(x))\cdot 1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,g(x))\cdot g'(x)
$$

---

Note: the symbol $*$ in real analysis is usually reserved for an operator called "[convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)".

Comment: Thanks, now I see it!

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Let $$F (x)=f (x,y (x)). $$

$$df=f_x dx +f_y dy $$

$$dy=y'(x)dx $$

$$\frac {dF}{dx}=f_x+f_y.\frac {dy}{dx} $$

For example, 
$$f (x,y)=x^2+7y $$
$$y (x)=\pi x $$

then
$$\frac{dF}{dx}=2x+7\pi $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x,y(x))$ is the functional value of the composition $g: x \mapsto (x, y(x)) =: (x,z) \mapsto f(x,z)$ for every suitable $x$. So chain rule gives 
$$
g'(x) = (D_{1}f(x,z), D_{2}f(x,z)) \cdot (1, y'(x)) = D_{1}f(x,y(x)) + D_{2}f(x,y(x))y'(x).
$$

The problem shows the importance of notation :).